# anova versus LME

Tags: anova, ancova, lme4-nlme

I have a very simple model and problem, but am confusing myself in model comparisons. Please help.

I am running a model that is a single group pre-/post-test design. No control group. I am running an GLM model where the Y and X1 (pre) are continuous. I have a bunch of covariates and want to include their interactions with pretest. Observations are nested (ICC=.07).

Here is the model:

$AnxietyPOST ~ AnxietyPRE + covariates + covariates*AnxietyPRE$

In R I am running the function `lme`from the package `nlme` with the following code:

```
lme(AnxTc~AnxTb+COVARIATES,data=d, random=~1|Group))
```

, where Covariates is a list of covariates I delete here for simplicity.

My questions is this:

1. I understand that the significance of the PREtest score is indicative of change, but what parameters are best reported? The particular coefficient is not that useful because it is the correlation between pre and post.
2. When I run anova.lme, I get F tests for each parameter in the model, but not an overall F AND the results are slightly different. Why?
3. Similarly, lme and aov are producing different results. Is this because of compound symmetry?

HELP?!?!

Comment: It is not clear what is intended to be compared and the reasons thereof.Be specific.